# Does there exist a path connected metric space , in which at least one open ball is countable ?

Tags: metric-spaces, cardinals, connectedness

Does there exist a path connected metric space with more than one point , in which at least one open ball is countable ?

Answer (score 4):

At least, if the open ball $B$ is connected, this is false because then if $B$ is countable, it has only has one point. To see this, suppose there are two distinct points $a,b\in B$. Then $d$ restricted to $B$ is a metric on $B$.

Consider S= $\left \{ d(a,x) :x\in B\right \}$. If $S$ contains every real number in $(0,d(a,b))$ then $B$ is uncountable, which is a contradiction.

If there is a real number $z\in (0,d(a,b))$ such that $d(a,x)\neq z$ for any $x\in B$, then the sets $\left \{ x\in B:d(a,x) >z\right \}$ and $\left \{ x\in B:d(a,x) <z\right \}$ provide a separation of $B$ and so $B$ cannot be connected.

Comment: It is not true in general that, if a metric space is connected, then so is each of its open balls.  Consider, for example, the subspace of the plane consisting of the $x$-axis and all the vertical lines of the form $L_q=\{(q,y):y\in\mathbb R\}$ for rational $q$.

Comment: Nice example. I will amend my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be a path connected space with more than one point, and let $B \subset X$ be an open ball. If $B$ is just a single point then by an easy argument $B=X$, a contradiction.

So there are two points $x \ne y \in B$, and using them I'll prove that $B$ has contains a subset of the cardinality of the reals.

Applying path connectedness of $X$, let $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$ be a continuous path with $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$. By continuity of $\gamma$ there exists $T \in (0,1]$ such that $\gamma[0,T] \subset B$. It cannot happen that $\gamma(T)=x$ for all such $T$, because if so then taking $T_0$ to be the supremum of such $T$ we would have $\gamma(T_0)=x \ne y$, and so $T_0 \ne 1$, but then by taking small enough $\delta>0$ we would have $\gamma[0,T_0+\delta] \subset B$ contradicting that $T_0$ is the supremum.

So we may therefore take $T \in (0,1]$ so that $\gamma[0,T] \subset B$ and $\gamma(T) \ne x$. Now consider the function
$$f : [0,T] \to \mathbb{R}, \quad f(t) = d(x,\gamma(t))
$$
This is a continuous function. By the intermediate value theorem its image $f[0,T]$ contains the entire nontrivial closed interval $[0,d(x,f(T))]$. So for each $D \in [0,d(x,f(T))]$ there exists a point $z \in B$ such that $d(x,z)=D$. It follows that the image $\gamma[0,T] \subset B$ contains a subset of cardinality equal to the reals.

Comment: why by continuity there is $T \in (0,1]$ such that $\gamma [0,T] \subset B$ ?

Comment: @SaunDev: The function $\gamma : [0,1] \to X$ is continuous, $B \subset X$ is an open set, and $\gamma(0)=x \in B$, and therefore there exists $\delta>0$ such that $\gamma[0,\delta) \subset B$. Take $T=\delta/2$.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, $X$ is not even connected:

Since $B$ contains more than one point, choose $b_{0}, b_{1}\in B$ and let $d(b_{0}, b_{1})=r>0$. Choose $0<s<r$, such that $d(b_{0},x)\neq s$ for any $x\in X$. This is possible since $B$ is countable and since $\left \{ x\in X:d(x,b_{0})=s \right \}\subseteq B$

But now, the sets $\left \{ x\in X:d(x,b_{0})<s \right \}$ and $\left \{ x\in X:d(x,b_{0})>s \right \}$ are open, disjoint and their union is $X$. That is, they form a separation of $X$.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is true. Take two points in an open ball. Since there is a path between the points and the image of the path is uncountable, the open ball is uncountable.

Comment: How is the image of the path uncountable ?

Comment: You make a good point. I realized I was assuming that the path was injective.

Comment: It's also possible that your path, between two points in the given ball, makes a detour outside that ball, so the last bit of your argument needs more justification.  I think, though, that you can get around both problems, first by replacing the path with an injective one (essentially by skipping any loops, though this needs careful proof), and then by using continuity to infer that, even if the path goes outside the ball, a sufficiently short (but nontrivial) initial segment will be within the ball.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: injectivity is the problem and it's not as easy as it seems, I don't think. The issue is proving that the identification space you pass to is uncountable.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: it is also clear that if $Y$ is connected, then $B$ cannot be finite. In fact, every point of $B$ is a limit point of $B$.